# Matlab - deploying exe which uses custom toolbox

Tags: matlab, deployment, dependencies, exe, dependency-management

I have an matlab application that I want to deploy as .exe. This application (A) needs to use classes from another project (B), however I dont want to include B into A. My intention would be to create a toolbox from B and have A then use that toolbox.

However from how I understand the matlab infrastructure there is the matlab ide and also a seperate runtime that you can install. And a deployed .exe would use that seperate runtime, while toolboxes would only be integrated into the ide? Do I misunderstand that, and if not how could I achieve this:

> This application (A) needs to use classes from another project (B),
> however I dont want to include B into A. My intention would be to
> create a toolbox from B and have A then use that toolbox.

Comment: You cannot do that. When creating a stand-alone executable, all code must be included. Stand-alone executables cannot run external code, because that would open up a way for people without a MATLAB license to run arbitrary MATLAB code. So the executable you create with MATLAB Compiler must be completely self-contained.